# How to delete certain element in string during recursion (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

Every recursion I will get a new string like this: [3 x i32]
But I don't want to get [5 x i32][4 x i32]... but to modify them as [5 x [4 x [3 x i32]]], how can I get that?
(Suppose the original string is in variable *old*. And new string is stored in *new*.)
Thanks.

Comment: give us the input and actual output you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
def step(old = '', start = 5)
  if old =~ /\A\z/ or old =~ /\A\[\]\z/
    old = "[#{start} x i32]"
  else
    old.sub!(/(\d+)( x i32)/) do |match|
      num = Integer($1)
      "#{$1} x [#{num - 1}#{$2}]"
    end
  end
end

new = step
puts new
1.upto(5) do
  new = step(new)
  puts new
end
```

Comment: what is the input to your program and output?